# Mysql server not working, I tried everything

Tags: mysql

I tried everything but always get this. I reinstalled mysql ~10 times now and always the same thing happens.

```
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-06-08 06:16:49 UTC; 54s ago
  Process: 25195 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 25203 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 25203 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "Server startup in progress"
    Error: 13 (Permission denied)

Jun 08 06:16:49 vilciens systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
Jun 08 06:16:49 vilciens systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Jun 08 06:16:49 vilciens systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Jun 08 06:16:49 vilciens systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jun 08 06:16:49 vilciens systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 08 06:16:49 vilciens systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

Comment: What OS? How did you install it? Notice the Permission denied? What is `ls -laZ /usr/sbin/mysqld`? How are you starting it? Take note was commands are done as root. Include `journalctl -u mysql.service` from the last start.

Comment: installed on ubuntu 19.10. I used everything I could find apt, apt-get, even from links. i tried starting it as a service and using the installed script.

Comment: Be logged in as "root".

Answer (score 0):

try this

sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/